# Dynamiclly move data from a table to another in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have two tables in two different worksheets under the same workbook.

Table 1 & Table 2

1. I want to create a function that will take table 1 & table 2 as
   parameters.
2. Copy cells from table 1 to table 2 but we have have 2
   questions:

Which column to update and which row to update to know the proper cell.

Which column should be based on the naming of the column example:

Table 1.**Column 1** will be Table 2.**Column 1**
So detecting the column to update will be based on matching column names.

Which row should be last row in table 2 + 1.

So whatever the number of columns is there, function should search and match in table 2 based on column name.

I don't need exact syntax, I just want to know the how would the logic go.

**UPDATE:**

This is an example:

Image: http://gdurl.com/9sf5

I will call the function like this:

DynamicTableMigration(Table 1, Table 2)

So the function will move all data in table 1 to table 2 matching columns based on identical column names like in the image example.

Comment: Could you share an example? The description is very blury

Comment: @AnalystCave.com: I add an update with image. Let me know if it is clear or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables are List Objects. Their row and column parameters can be found by

```
RowAfterLast = ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).Range.Row + ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).Range.Rows
ColumnAfterLast = ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).Range.Column + ws(j).ListObjects(ListObj(j)).Range.Columns
```

The *.Row* and *.Column* parameters spit out the top left corner of the range while the *.Rows* and *.Columns* measure the width and depth in number of cells.
To tell the Column number of a header you'll just need to search in the header for the string. If the name may vary you can search in xlPart or use a loop that outputs the column if a *Like* argument is fulfilled.

```
ws(j).Range(Header).Find(title1, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
```

Comment: By the way, if your headers are identical you'll simply need to identify the leftmost value of the record and offset for each row.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just have 1 issue open..If the find function didn't find the desired column in destination table? I tried and found it gave error, any ideas?

Comment: Hi,
The find.count is getting the column index in the entire sheet not in the table:

'DestColumnIndex = destTable.Range.Find(ColumnName, MatchCase:= _
                    True, SearchFormat:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).column'

If first table column is on D then DestColumnIndex should be 1
But it is getting 4.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Substract the starting column then add one? DestColumnIndex = destTable.Range.Find(ColumnName, MatchCase:= _ True, SearchFormat:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).column-destTable.Range.column+1

Comment: thx, this could be an option, but I meant is there a way to use .find and .column together in listObject?

Comment: *ListObject.Range.Find(...).Column* would still be an absolute reference.